# Node.js creating a module to gather memory (ram) info?

Tags: javascript, node.js

What I'm trying to do is printing out the local memory usage every X (in this case just 1) seconds in Node.js on a Windows machine. The code with the function of the actual gathering of that data needs to be in a separate module. This is my current code:

in the `server.js`:

```
mem_stats = require("./mem_stats.js");

setInterval(function () {
  mem_stats.update();
  console.log(mem_stats.mem_total);
}, 1000);
```

in the `mem_stats.js`:

```
var exec = require("child_process").exec,
  mem_total,
  mem_avail,
  mem_used;

exports.update = function () {
  exec("wmic ComputerSystem get TotalPhysicalMemory", function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    mem_total = parseInt(stdout.split("\r\n")[1].toString()) / 1073741824; // 1024^3
  });

  exec("wmic OS get FreePhysicalMemory", function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    mem_avail = parseInt(stdout.split("\r\n")[1]) / 1048576; // 1024^2
  });
}

exports.mem_total = mem_total;
exports.mem_avail = mem_avail;
exports.mem_used = mem_total - mem_avail;
```

I'm suspecting (/ pretty sure) it has something to do with the asynchronous way of JS but I can't seem to figure out a way to get around it (with callbacks etc.). I've tried a lot of things by now but whatever I seem to do, I always end up with an `undefined` being printed...

Changing my code to something like this did not solve anything either:

```
function mem_total () {
  var temp;
  exec("wmic ComputerSystem get TotalPhysicalMemory", function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    temp = parseInt(stdout.split("\r\n")[1].toString()) / 1073741824; // 1024^3
  });
  return temp;
};

function mem_avail () {
  var temp;
  exec("wmic OS get FreePhysicalMemory", function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    temp = parseInt(stdout.split("\r\n")[1]) / 1048576; // 1024^2
  });
  return temp;
};

exports.mem_total = mem_total();
exports.mem_avail = mem_avail();
```

I just don't get it.

I'm aware of the fact that this question might look (quite) a bit stupid, but I don't really have much experience with coding JS, I'm very much used to more C(++) oriented languages. But thanks anyway.

Comment: Although this is unrelated to your question, the `os` module contains simpler methods for what you're doing here. `os.totalmem()` returns the number of system memory you have in bytes, and `os.freemem()` returns the amount of free memory.

Comment: I am aware of that, but the problem is that I'm trying to do this too for CPU usage/temperature and GPU usage/temperature. However those modules are a bit more complicated because there's just a whole lot more information going on in there, so showing the problem off with the RAM one was the easiest/most straight forward/cleanest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your second example, the command will execute in the following manner

```
function mem_total () {
  var temp;
  // call exec now. Since it is async, When the function finishes, 
  // call the callback provided
  exec("wmic ComputerSystem get TotalPhysicalMemory", function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    // temp is modified AFTER mem_total has returned
    temp = parseInt(stdout.split("\r\n")[1].toString()) / 1073741824; // 1024^3
  });

  // return temp before exec finishes.
  return temp;
};
```

Maybe you want something like the following:

```
function mem_total (callback) {
  var temp;
  exec("wmic ComputerSystem get TotalPhysicalMemory", function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    // temp is modified AFTER the function has returned
    temp = parseInt(stdout.split("\r\n")[1].toString()) / 1073741824; // 1024^3

    callback(error, temp);
  });
};
```

And call the function in the following manner

```
mem_total(function(err, mem) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }
    console.log('total memory is ', mem);
});
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but when you create a node callback, you should always use the standard signature, `callback(error, results)`.